# ERROR: column "increment_by" does not exist - Postgres 10 and Navicat for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, navicat

I recently upgraded my Postgres version from 9.4 to Postgres 10. All the apps that interact with the database behave themselves except my **Navicat for Postgres**.

When I try to do any with sequences in Navicat, I get this error:

```
SELECT last_value, increment_by, max_value, min_value, cache_value, is_called, is_cycled FROM "schema"."seq-name"
ERROR:  column "increment_by" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT last_value, increment_by, max_value, min_value, cache.
```

For example, if I try do a structured sync in Navicat or try view the sequences associated with a particular schema, I get the error above.

I am using Navicat for Postgres version 11.2.16 (64 bit).

I've checked for updates etc in Navicat but I'm already up to date apparently.

Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently Navicat didn't realize that Postgres 10 introduced [`pg_sequence`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-sequence.html) to provide information about a sequence

Comment: Yeah - it seems so. What's frustrating is that Navicat for Postgres 12 and up works just fine - but I want to avoid paying for yet another license